# defining accumulate_n? (higher-order functions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, higher-order-functions, accumulate

I would like to define a function `accumulate_n(op, init, sequences)` using `accumulate(op, init, seq)` as such:

The function `accumulate_n(op, init, sequences)` is similar to `accumulate(op, init, seq)` except that it takes as its third argument a sequence of sequences of equal length. It applies the accumulation function `op` to combine all the first elements of the sequences, all the second elements of the sequences, and so on, and returns a sequence of the results. For instance, if s is a sequence containing four sequences, `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]`, then the value of `accumulate_n(lambda x, y: x+y, 0, s)` should be the sequence `[22, 26, 30]`.

```
def accumulate(op, init, seq):
    if not seq:
        return init
    else:
        return op(seq[0], accumulate(op, init, seq[1:]))

def accumulate_n(op, init, sequences):
    if (not sequences) or (not sequences[0]):
        return type(sequences)()
    else:
        return ( [accumulate(op, init, ??)]
               + accumulate_n(op, init, ??) )
```

but I'm stuck at the `??` part as I'm at a loss of what to include in it. I suppose I could use the `map` built-in function but still quite uncertain of what to do.

Below are examples of what the function is supposed to  execute:

```
accumulate_n(lambda x,y: x+y, 0, [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])   
# [9, 12]
accumulate_n(lambda x,y: x+y, 0, [[1,4],[5,7],[9,10]])  
# [15, 21]
accumulate_n(lambda x,y: x+y, 0, [[9,8],[7,6],[5,4]])   
# [21, 18]
```

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: it looks to me like you could just use `reduce` for `accumulate`... still note sure what `accumulate_n` is suppose to do...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry for the unclear question! just edited my question explaining what `accumulate_n` is supposed to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you’re looking to get:

- a list of every sequence’s first element, which could be `[s[0] for s in sequences]`, and
- a list of every sequence’s remaining elements, which could be `[s[1:] for s in sequences]`.

In all:

```
def accumulate(op, init, seq):
    if not seq:
        return init
    else:
        return op(seq[0], accumulate(op, init, seq[1:]))

def accumulate_n(op, init, sequences):
    if (not sequences) or (not sequences[0]):
        return type(sequences)()
    else:
        heads = [s[0] for s in sequences]
        tails = [s[1:] for s in sequences]

        return ([accumulate(op, init, heads)]
               + accumulate_n(op, init, tails))
```

but for what it’s worth, I’d do this row-wise instead of column-wise and require `init` to be a sequence itself:

```
def accumulate_n_(op, init, sequences):
    try:
        head = next(sequences)
    except StopIteration:
        return init

    return accumulate_n_(
        op,
        [op(x, y) for x, y in zip(init, head)],
        sequences,
    )

def accumulate_n(op, init, sequences):
    return accumulate_n_(op, init, iter(sequences))
```

Cleaner imperative:

```
def accumulate_n(op, init, sequences):
    for s in sequences:
        init = [op(x, y) for x, y in zip(init, s)]

    return init
```

Finally, with `functools.reduce`:

```
def zipper(op):
    return lambda xs, ys: [op(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)]

def accumulate_n(op, init, sequences):
    return reduce(zipper(op), sequences, init)
```

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `zip` function, in conjunction with the use of `*` to unpack
a list into arguments, is handy for selecting the nth value from a
sequence of sequences:

```
def accumulate_n(op, init, sequences):
    if (not sequences) or (not sequences[0]):
        return type(sequences)()
    else:
        return [accumulate(op, init, i) for i in zip(*sequences)]
```